# In log4cplus-1.1.2, why the type of Loger::value is NOT SharedLoggerImplPtr, but spi::LoggerImpl *?

Tags: logging, log4cplus

I read the souce code of log4cplus-1.1.2 recently, and found that `SharedLoggerImplPtr` seem to be the better type for `Loger::value` than `spi::LoggerImpl *`。

The definition of `Loger::value` in logger.h at line 284-285:

```
/** This is a pointer to the implementation class. */
spi::LoggerImpl * value;
```

The implementation of ctor and dtor in logger.cxx at line 105-110, 149-153:

```
Logger::Logger (spi::LoggerImpl * ptr)
    : value (ptr)
{
    if (value)
        value->addReference (); 
}

Logger::~Logger ()
{
    if (value)
        value->removeReference ();
}
```

Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I vaguely remember that this was because of template instantiation exports issues on Windows. Basically, Visual Studio would complain that while `Logger` is exported, `SharedPtr<LoggerImpl>` is not exported. But marking whole template for export has other consequences and issues.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, both template `SharedObjectPtr` and the instantiated `SharedPtr<LoggerImpl>` are not exported.